# Most RESTful way of storing data that is to be served as JSON?

Tags: django, json, post, get, request

I have a Django server responsible for serving JSON formatted files to a controller machine. My server gets data from POST requests and serve JSON files on GET requests. I'm wondering what is the most RESTful and efficient way of creating this bridge on the server?

I'm considering creating a JSON model and storing instances on my database for each POST request and pack the instances into JSON files dynamically and serve them on GET requests. The alternative would be creating JSON files on POST requests, saving them in a folder on the server, and serving these files on GET requests.

Which way is better and why? Or am I failing to see a completely better method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked into [json serialization](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/serialization/#id2) with natural keys and dependencies etc. to control the fields that are serialized. I also tried using the middleware [wodofstuff](http://code.google.com/p/wadofstuff/wiki/DjangoFullSerializers) to allow for deeper foreign key serialization. However, I decided to use templates to render the JSON response.

Some pitfalls are

- I am responsible for formatting the JSON (more prone to mistakes like a missing semi-colon)
- I am responsible for escaping characters
- Renders slower than buit-in serialization?

Some advantages are

- I have control over what is serialized (even if the underlying models is changed)
- I can format many to many or foreign key relationships on the JSON file however I like

TLDL; In my case, the format of the JSON file I needed was very custom. It had dictionary in list in dictionary. Some fields are iterative so I have for loops in the templates to render them. However, the format requires some of the fields in the iterated object to be encapsulated in a list as oppose to a dictionary.

This was an obstacle I ran into while considering [simplejson](http://simplejson.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html). By using something like

```
import simplejson as json
def encode_complex(obj):
    if isinstance(obj, complex):
        return [obj.real, obj.imag]
    raise TypeError(repr(o) + " is not JSON serializable")
json.dumps(2 + 1j, default=encode_complex)
'[2.0, 1.0]'
```

I could manage to return iterated data; however, I needed iteration in iteration and custom object types (list or dict) to encapsulate certain iterations. Finally, (may it be lack of knowledge or lack of patience) I decided to just do it in the templates.

I feel like rendering it through templates is not the most scalable or 'smartest' way of doing it, could it possibly be done in a better way? Please feel free to prove me right or wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you creating files? You can let a Django view return a JSON response instead of a HTML response:

```
import json

# in your view:
data = {}
return HttpResponse(json.dumps(data), mimetype="application/json")
```

Construct the JSON data dynamically from the available data and if the JSON responses are big, add caching (e.g., [`memcached`](http://memcached.org/) or [`Varnish`](https://www.varnish-cache.org/)).

This will prevent certain problems (what to do if a GET request is done but there is no JSON file yet?). This way you can generate the JSON based on the data that you have or return JSON with an error message instead.

Comment: Right, after much research, I found the [serialization](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/serialization/) support for Django models. I will attempt to structure my classes (with correct foreign keys) and implement natural_key() methods. Will be back with an answer once I try that out.